# In PyTorch, can I load a tensor from file directly to the GPU, without using CPU memory?

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on feature generation before I train a model in PyTorch. I wish to save my features as PyTorch tensors on disk for later use in training.

One of my features ("Feature A") is calculated on a CPU while another feature ("Feature B") must be calculated from that CPU on a GPU (some linear algebra stuff). I have an unusual limitation: on my university cluster, jobs which don't use GPUs have CPU memory limits of 1TB each while jobs which do use GPUs have CPU memory limits of 4GB with GPU memory limits of 48GB. Feature A and Feature B are each approximately 10GB.

Naturally, I want to first calculate Feature A using CPUs only then save Feature A to disk. In another job (this one with GPU access and thus the 4GB CPU memory limitation), I want to load Feature A directly to GPU, compute Feature B, then save Feature B to disk.

With Feature A computed and saved to disk, I've tried:

```
feaB = torch.load(feaAfile, map_location=torch.device('cuda'))
```

And yet I max-out my CPU memory. I've confirmed cuda is available.

In the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html) I see that in loading tensors they "are first deserialized on the CPU..."

I wonder if there is any way to avoid a CPU memory implication when I want to load only onto the GPU? If the tensor must first be copied to the CPU, could I use some sort of 4GB buffer? Thanks so much in advance.

EDIT: per discussion in the comments, I no longer need to do this. But the question itself, of loading a tensor to the GPU without using CPU memory, remains unanswered so I'm leaving this question up.

Comment: Just as an aside, only allowing an application to use 4GB of CPU memory while using a GPU with 48GB of memory is really a bad idea.  NVIDIA typically recommends a minimum 2x ratio,  (96GB) below which you start to seriously constrain what you can do with the GPU.  Limiting to 4GB with a 48GB GPU is really bizarre thinking.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes, I agree!

Comment: @RobertCrovella actually - I'm able to request up to 128 CPUs for the one GPU, giving me 512 GB total CPU memory. But afaik this won't help me...

Comment: Why would that not help?

Comment: Can a 10GB object exist across the memory allocated to 3 CPUs?

Comment: Yes.  You may need to learn more about how this stuff works.  All of the CPUs running under a given OS share the same address space.  Allocations are not inherently limited to 4GB.  That is just a number being imposed by your job scheduler.

Comment: Ok thanks @RobertCrovella, I think this is solved for my own purposes. I think I'll leave this question up, though, because the question itself, the "load directly to GPU" part, remains unsolved and an answer might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: You could load the tensor in smaller parts, then recombine on the GPU with stack or concat.